# How can I get Mac address of all systems in LAN without Internet in PHP?

Tags: php, networking, lan

How can I get MAC address of all systems in LAN without Internet in PHP? Is this possible without using any extensions or with Core PHP 5.6+?

Comment: Is your Code able to access to routing table of its networks router? Because  just over HTTP-Header you won't receive any MAC. it's not possible without LAN/Network unless you have another physical connection to the other devices,

Answer (score 0):

#### How to Get MAC Address of all System in LAN without Internet.

On Linux install netdiscover if not installed

```
apt-get install netdiscover -y
```

usage: from terminal

```
netdiscover -i eth0
```

*replace interface with your interface.*

From PHP:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec("netdiscover -i eth0");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

On Windows:

```
arp -a
```